# How to set className as parameter for BeanPropertyRowMapper<>() in java

Tags: java, class, assign, classname

I am trying to set a class as the beanPropertyRowMapper.

```
query.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<ClassName>());
```

I need to get the class from a string. I tried the following:

```
Class<?> mapperClass = Class.forName(stringValue);
query.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper< mapperClass >());
```

which doesn't work. How can I do this? The result should be equivalent to

```
query.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Person>());
```

where `Person` is a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
Class mapperClass = Class.forName(stringValue);
BeanPropertyRowMapper mapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper(mapperClass);
```

should to the trick. Notice the absence of `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can't. Javas Generics system doesn't support that kind of polymorphism.